# IOS how to completely remove a View

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to hide a view completely. I am new to ios. But I have great working experience in android.

So in android We can set visibility to gone. and it completely removes the view from layout. Same I want to do in IOS. here is the layout/design example

View 1 
View 2 ( it is the one I want to hide and show) 
View 3

now when I want to hide the view 2 I want the space of view 2 also vanish from screen and View 1 and View 3 must stick together . and when view 2 is set to visible then it must display in sequence. i.e View 1,2,3

Right now what I am doing is setting **view2.ishidden = true**  but its not working in the way I want.

> Please tell me what is equivalent to view.gone of android in IOS. ???

Comment: use this  `view2.removeFromSuperview()`

Comment: then how to add it back to same place ?

Comment: To add view use -> `view.addSubview(view2)` and `view2.frame = ...` and to remove `view2.removeFromSuperview()`

Comment: If you want to remove and then add later, that's a purpose of isHidden property

Comment: if hidden don't fulfill you must use  `view2.removeFromSuperview()` and `view.addSubview(view2)` for adding again

Comment: There is a component called "UIStackView" and it is the component where you can get the view.gone functionality in android. When you put 3-4 views inside stackview and make one hidden, the rest will layout themselves properly.

Comment: search about UIStackView

Comment: Even you can set view2 height as 0.

Comment: view2.alpha = 0.0

Comment: @SharadChauhan alpha will still take a blank space which I really do not want to do \

Comment: what do meant by this ?

Comment: You can remove the constraints and give view new constraints. So when you want to show, create it and update your constraints else remove it and update constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways in achieving this but what you are missing here is some key information on how your layout is being set.

I will assume that the 3 views you are having are vertically aligned, are one next to each other and have equal width.

Programmatically what we are looking at from horizontal perspective this is done:

```
let firstLeading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view1, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: parent, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
let betweenSecondAndFirst = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view2, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view1, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
let secondEqualWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view2, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view1, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
let betweenThirdAndSecond = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view3, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view2, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
let lastEqualWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view3, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view1, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0) // Note to view1 to make things easier
let lastTrailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view3, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: parent, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
```

And when the second is being skipped we may simply disable `betweenThirdAndSecond` and add `betweenThirdAndFirst` as:

```
let betweenThirdAndFirst = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view3, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view1, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
```

You can play with properties on constraints to enable or disable them. Or you can simply use priorities and toggle them for instance from 900 to 100. You can actually setup all of these constraints in storyboard and then drag the 2 as outlets into your code. Then simply have:

```
func setMiddleViewShown(_ shown: Bool) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.betweenThirdAndSecond.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: shown ? 900.0 : 100.0)
        self.betweenThirdAndFirst.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: shown ? 100.0 : 900.0)
        self.view2.alpha = shown ? 1.0 : 0.0
        parent.layoutIfNeeded() // parent is most likely "self.view"
    }
}
```

This way is probably best from what you can control (mostly animations). But you may as well use `UIStackView` which has methods to insert or remove views. `UICollectionView` should work as well. Or you know.. just do it all programmatically, ignore constraints and simply set `frame` for each of the views.

A minimum I can think of in using `UIStackView` is the following and it works:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let views: [UIView] = [
    { let view = UIView(); view.backgroundColor = .red; return view; }(),
    { let view = UIView(); view.backgroundColor = .green; return view; }(),
    { let view = UIView(); view.backgroundColor = .blue; return view; }()
    ]

    lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 50.0, y: 100.0, width: 300.0, height: 200.0))
        self.view.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.backgroundColor = .black
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        return stackView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        stackView.addArrangedSubview(views[0])
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(views[1])
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(views[2])
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            if self.stackView.arrangedSubviews.count == 3 {
                self.views[1].alpha = 0.0
                self.stackView.removeArrangedSubview(self.views[1])
            } else {
                self.views[1].alpha = 1.0
                self.stackView.insertArrangedSubview(self.views[1], at: 1)
            }
            self.stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: but isnt there a way without pplaying with constraints

Comment: @Androidteem There is: Use UIStackView.

Comment: I am in stackview now. after reading comments above. I have put view 1 , 2,3 in stackview vertical aligned. and with spacing of 10

Comment: still the UITextLabel is taking space but yet it stays hidden

Comment: @Androidteem We will have to see what you have setup and how you manipulate these views. Try updating your question. I am sure there is just a small thing missing.

Comment: @Androidteem Please check the edit. I have added my example of stack view. It is very minimalistic but it can help you with your setup.

Comment: in your example you are setting views in stack view all by programatically. cant We use stackview made in IB and just use its outlets

Comment: @Androidteem Sure. It is exactly the same. All you do is have view2 as outlet and manipulate that one in conjunction with stack view the same way I did it. But make sure the outlets are NOT weak for views you are removing.

Comment: @Androidteem It is important to know that if an outlet is weak you should not remove it from super view or remove it from stack view in this case because doing so will set it to nil as view will be deallocated. Same goes for disabling constraints.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. But for generally asking. in ios for hiding view completely All we need to do is to set their constraint

Comment: great help indeed/

Comment: @Androidteem Well you may do it with constraints plus setting alpha to zero or isHidden to true. Constraints alone are usually bad idea.